# Sorting large files on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

On a windows 2008 Server, the below more and sort command is being used to sort a large csv file (20MB) by the first column. But the command is still running after 20 minutes! What is the best way to sort large csv files in Windows?

```
more input.csv +1 | sort > sortedInput.csv
```

Comment: [Sort](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation) of [GNU core utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) can be compiled also on Windows as console application which is extremely fast on sorting large files and has additional lots of powerful features the native `sort.exe` of Windows does not have. The text editor UltraEdit is installed with a Windows console `sort.exe` compiled from GNU core utilities and uses it on sorting a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort input.csv > sorted.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have to bet, your file has more than 65535 lines and the `more` command is waiting for you to press a key (`more` command makes a pause after each 65535 lines)

Without more information on the `.csv` file characteristics, this can be used as a starting point

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    < input.csv (
        set /p header=
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(!header!
        endlocal
        findstr "^" | sort 
    ) > output.csv
```

This will

- open the input file for reading
- read the first line (max 1021 characters)
- output the firstline (delayed expansion is needed)
- read the rest of the file (`findstr`) and pipe the data to `sort` command
- send anything to the output file

Please, note that both `set /p` and `findstr` have several limitations that could make this approach fail.